# Android 4.0 save content of asp page for offline viewing

Tags: android, ssl, sharepoint-2010

I'm a junior developer who has been working on a RSS Reader.

I'm trying to download a webpage from my app for offline viewing but I am having a few issues.
When I try to download an asp page I don't seem to get the right content, but instead a html page with asp form widgets.

Can anyone help me with understanding what's going on and how I could possibly download the content of the page?

I should also mention the webpage is a sharepoint webpage using https ssl authentication, using httpclient as my means to connect and download the webpage.

Comment: this sounds more like a server side problem (server serving the wrong content) than a client issue

Comment: What do you mean with asp form widget. On a SharePoint page nearly the whole content is part of a form. So there will be a HTML form element on the page. Have you compared the content you've downloaded with the content of the page when you access it with a normal browser? Another problem might be that you have to authenticate before you being able to access the real page you're requesting. Perhaps you could post the content you receive.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with ASP you usually need to send __VIEWSTATE and _*EVENTVALIDATION tokens in your HttpPost and other requests. You can get those once by calling HttpGet on the basic page and using Patten with regexes or a simple str.contains("*_VIEWSTATE") and strip it out of the HTML and send with every request.

If you're not doing any POSTs, just basic GETs, then make sure you're setting the headers appropriately, as so:

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet("YOUR SITE'S URL");         
req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setHeader("Host", "YOUR SITE'S ROOT PAGE");
req.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ...");
req.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
req.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
req.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en");
req.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(req, localContext);
```

Don't forget about the possible session cookie you can store in httpcontext and also pass in with every execute as seen above:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

The best way to go about it in theory is to download Fiddler, run the site in Chrome, see what's going on and emulate actual browser requests in your app: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/